# Link outside button

Tags: html, css, button

I have button on my website. But it is clickable not only on the button itself but anywhere to the right outside of the button border. What should I do?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Oh i didnt realised. Sorry. Im working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `<a>` tag around the `<div>` tag of the button, which is very large. This `<a>` tag is the reason, such a large area is clickable. It would be best to format your button in an `<a>` tag instead of the `<div>`. This would resolve your problem. In general, it is best to avoid wrapping semantically block elements like `div`, `p` etc. inside inline elements like `a` or `span`.

```
<a href="#show-works" class="works">
```

*Make sure, that the `<a>` tag is properly marked as `display: block` or `display: inline-block`, to prevent having it inline.*

**Here is a screenshot of your [website](http://hectix.ml)'s inspected elements and the reason of your problem:**

[image: dev tools of the website]

Comment: Problem solved, i removed the div class and add class to <a> tag instead.